# Woocommerce: interrupt checkout just before payment step based on user roll

Tags: wordpress

We are looking into adding a wholesale signup to a retail woocommerce website, and would like to make it so that if a customer is already registered as a normal retail customer (or is a new customer), and has items in their cart, and would like to apply to become a wholesale reseller during the checkout process 'that they can check a box (preferred), or press a button just before the final payment step.

I am presently using the "Woocommerce MultiStep Checkout Wizard" plugin that is ajax based, and presents the checkout steps in the following order..

1. Billing Details
2. Ship Details
3. View Order (with cart items and order summary)
4. Payment

Checking that box in step 3, or pressing that button should interrupt the checkout process and present them with an info & additional wholesale signup page with some extra user meta fields (e.g., fed tax id information, etc) that would gather any additional required information, and change their roll to something like "Wholesale Applicant", and would then postpone the final payment step (based on that specific roll), and will prevent final payment until their roll is either changed to "Wholesale Customer" (accepted), or is rejected by the shop admin. In the latter case, their roll would be manually reset to "Retail Customer".

I also am using the "Varktech Pricing Deals for Woocommerce" plugin to manage wholesale discounts based on the user's roll

An email should also be sent to the shop admin whenever a customer wants to go the wholesale route.

NOTE: the wholesale signup page should have a way to cancel and complete the payment step - in case they change their mind too.

I am not a programmer, but have searched for a plugin that could do this with no luck (so far).

Answer (score 0):

I think sometimes newly added checkout/cart based plugins add/edit/update, Please (Resetting checkout fields ) follow below links

**Resetting the checkout fields** >>> To reset your fields back to the originals, go to WooCommerce > System Status > Tools and look for the “Checkout Fields” section. Click the ‘reset’ buttons and any customisations to your fields will be removed.

After that check all ... all for the best! ...